# Haproxy DNS resolving for log targets

Tags: dns, haproxy, consul

I use an elk stack for logging with haproxy 1.6.3 and I'm also using consul.
In haproxy I set the global log to

```
log logstash.service.consul:514 len 4096 local0 notice
```

I do know that older haproxy only resolves DNS when it's started. In newer haproxy version I can also use resolvers. And in 1.8 it's also possible to resolve SRV records.

But the documentation doesn't show that resolvers are usable with a log target. So does haproxy only resolve the log target at startup?

Consul itself uses an TTL of 0 for its DNS records.

I do know about consul-templates. But I would like to know how haproxy behaves without it.

Comment: I had almost the same issue. HAProxy uses `libc` functions for name resolution  which means it uses `/etc/resolv.conf`. So, I had to add Consul to `resolv.conf`. The problem with that is you can't just add a new name server with a different port in `resolv.conf`! So, I had to add `dnsmasq` to the mix just to forward Consul's 5300 to 53 on `localhost`. Of course in certain circumstances you can use `iptable` for port forwarding but it wasn't good enough for my case.

Comment: That's not really the issue. I do use forwarding with unbound and consul DNS records get resolved fine, so I do have this part covered. However I'm more interested if DNS records, which change at runtime, get correctly resolved to the new entry without restarting/reloading haproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it and definitely only resolves at startup of haproxy. Later changes of the DNS record are never resolved by haproxy for log targets.